# Conditionally formatting if multiple cells are not blank and the cell I am formatting is blank

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have created a spreadsheet and I need to have a blank cell highlighted if ever another cell in its row is not blank and am having trouble figuring it out. I know the basics behind conditional formatting in Google Sheets just need some advice.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

apply to range **A1:A**

enter custom formula: `=($B1<>"")*($A1="")`

logic: if **B** cell is not blank and **A** cell is blank then **A** cell gets highlighted

[image: 0]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?